# replace a nucleotide at a certain position in a dna sequence file

Tags: python, fasta

I have a fasta file, and another file contains the position, I want to replace at a certain position of each sequence  with a default setting, for example, my position file looks like
a/c 120, my replace table looks like a/c to W, so I want to get a new fasta file with the position 120 replaced with w.

The program was written in Python

So the first problem is I can't get to the correct position, for example, if I used 
my_seq_id[0:3], I got the sequence name! not the sequence.
The position file looks like 
id1   219    A/C

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import string
userInput1=raw_input("enter your sequence:")
userInput2=raw_input('enter your position file:')
fasta_file=userInput1
position_file=userInput2
result_file="outfile.txt"
id_list=list()
position_list=list()
nucleotide_list=list()
with open(position_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        line=line.strip()
        headerline = line.split()
        position=headerline[1]
        ID=headerline[0]
        nucleotide=headerline[2]
        nucleotide_list.add(nucleotide)
        position_list.add(position)
        id_list.add(ID)
fasta_sequence=SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file), 'fasta')
with open(result_file, 'w') as f:
    if seq_record.id in wanted and nucleotide_list="A/C":
        seq_record[position_list]="W\n"
        SeqIO.write([seq_record], f, "fasta")
```

Comment: Please provide some of your current implementation so we can help you out. SO exists to help, not to implement your problem for you. If you are interested in having someone do the work for you, check out [Rent a Coder](http://www.rent-acoder.com/).

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go with c.  Maybe some bash/awk/perl commands:

https://www.biostars.org/p/17680/

Comment: This code does not look *anything* like C -- the programming language. Are you sure you are not confusing C-the-language with C-the-nucleotid (as in CGAT)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit confusing, shouldn't:

```
fasta_sequence=SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file), 'fasta')
with open(result_file, 'w') as f:
    if seq_record.id in wanted and nucleotide_list="A/C":
        seq_record[position_list]="W\n"
        SeqIO.write([seq_record], f, "fasta")
```

be:

```
fasta_sequence=SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file), 'fasta')
with open(result_file, 'w') as f:
    if fasta_sequence[j].id in wanted and nucleotide_list[i]=="A/C":
        fasta_sequence[j].seq[position_list]="W\n"
        SeqIO.write([fasta_sequence[j]], f, "fasta")
```

Being i some counter to go through the nucleotide_list and j to go through fasta_sequence

What you can also do is iterate through fasta_sequence this way:

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(StringIO(data), "fasta"):
    print("%s %s" % (record.id, record.seq))
```

being id the id of each element and seq its sequence.

---- Update ----

I think I understood what you want to do, to go through each record in the file, check if the id is a match and then change the sequence in that position do:

```
#goes through each record in the file
for record in SeqIO.parse(StringIO(data), "fasta"):
    # check if id is wanted
    if record.id in id_list:
        # get list of every item in id_list that matches record.id
        positions_of_id_in_id_list = [i for i, j in enumerate(id_list) if j == record.id]
        for elem_position_lists in positions_of_id_in_id_list:
            # I think here you want to write the new record in the correct position (substitute "W\n" with new item. Maybe nucleotide[elem_position_lists]?)
            record.seq[position_list[elem_position_lists]] = "W\n"
# write new file
SeqIO.write(fasta_sequence, f, "fasta")
```

Comment: I tried but it is still not working. With "syntax error" at line 27 pointing to the "=" Help, how to go through each line from a vcf file, find matched id in the fasta file and replace in the defined position? I', totally confused.

Comment: It should be a == instead of = in the if clause. I'll edited the answer.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark as correct so others will know what to look for! Thanks